# Release NSArray assigned to UIBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

In my app i want to make array, add to toolbar and then release it. However when i release it my app crashes. Why so...? What to do to omit it?

```
UIImage *button1Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1Image.png"];
cameraToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init]; //declared in .h
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"qwerty" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(doAction)];
[button1 setImage:button1Image];
//same method to add flexItem and button2Image

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: button1, flexItem, button2, nil];
[cameraToolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
self.view = cameraToolbar;

[items release]; // here it crashes, why? How to fix?
[button1 release];
[button2 release];
[flexItem release];
[button1Image release]; // here i get "Incorrect decrement of the reference count 
//of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"
[button2Image release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] is a class method** which returns an array which is **autoreleased object**.so **u shouldnot release it**.

**if u use to create object with like alloc,copy,retain then only u have the responsibility to release them.**

```
NSArray *items=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:button1, flexItem, button2, nil];


............



[items release];
```

like this for button1Image object.take care

Comment: Great! However what with releasing buttonImages? I get this warning when i analyze..

Comment: anywhere for any object u can adopt this behaviour.

Comment: if u use alloc,retain,copy then u have to release it.in ios5 ARC will help us.till now we have to do manually.

Comment: The button image is also auto-released. Convenience class methods that start with the class name generally return auto-released objects.

Answer (score 0):

`button1Image` is assigned a object which is autoreleased and hence shouldn't be sent a release message. Memory management is based on object reference count and when count becomes zero, the memory will be released. A release message decrements the reference count by one.